# Edit default Cash On Delivery Payment module/extension

Tags: php

I am using Magento 1.9.

Guys i want to create a very simple change in the `Cash On Delivery Payment` the default module that comes with the freshly installed magento store.

I am not sure if there is a module/extension for this payment method.

I want to ask where it is located so i can check out the files of this payment method and edit what i want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php.

The block is app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Cashondelivery.php.

The settings are in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml (it's common file with some of the other payment methods, so search for cashondelivery).